# Ansible variable is undefined unless set as default

Tags: ansible

I am trying to add a new variable to an existing git repository full of Ansible files, that make heavy use of roles. So wherever `foo` is referenced, underneath

```
vars_files:
   - vars/aws.yml
   - vars/aws-credentials.yml
```

I've added the new line

```
   - vars/rpm-repo.yml
```

and I've created `vars/rpm-repo.yml` with contents:

```
---
yum_rpm_dir: https://example.com/repo/noarch
```

which is valid YAML according to the command given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20420243/495796) for checking whether a file is valid YAML.

And in `roles/foo/tasks/main.yml` I have changed a `yum` task to install this:

```
name: "{{ yum_rpm_dir }}/rest-api-{{ rest_api_version }}-1.noarch.rpm"
```

(the purpose of this explicit URL is to workaround a bug in our RPM repository.)

But I get:

```
fatal: [1.2.3.4]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'yum_rpm_dir' is undefined"}
```

So I thought, clearly I haven't understood the intricacies of how variables interact with roles in Ansible, so I'll add it as a default and that'll definitely work.

So I copied the file above to `roles/foo/defaults/main.yml` as well.

That works, but it's a hack. The whole point of making this a variable was that its value could be used by multiple roles without being copied and pasted.

**tl;dr:** How do I set a variable in Ansible properly so that it can be picked up by a role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simply that I had missed one file where the `foo` role was being used.

The reference to `foo` didn't look like this:

```
 roles:
    - foo
```

but like this:

```
 roles:
     - { role: foo, rest_api_version: "{{ blah_version }}" }
```

so I had overlooked it. Once I added the same reference to the vars file before that "call" to the foo role as well, it worked without the defaults file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify which version of `ansible` is the one you are using, and there are important changes from 1.x to 2.x.

[From the on-line documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable), the answer to

> How do I set a variable in Ansible properly so that it can be picked up by a role?

would be:

In 1.x, the precedence is as follows (with the last listed variables winning prioritization):

- “role defaults”, which lose in priority to everything and are the most easily overridden
- variables defined in inventory
- facts discovered about a system
- “most everything else” (command line switches, vars in play, included vars, role vars, etc.)
- connection variables (ansible_user, etc.)
- extra vars (-e in the command line) always win

In 2.x, the order of precedence is more specific (with the last listed variables winning prioritization):

- role defaults (Tasks in each role will see their own role’s defaults. Tasks defined outside of a role will see the last role’s defaults)
- inventory vars (Variables defined in inventory file or provided by dynamic inventory)
- inventory group_vars
- inventory host_vars
- playbook group_vars
- playbook host_vars
- host facts
- play vars
- play vars_prompt
- play vars_files
- registered vars
- set_facts
- role and include vars
- block vars (only for tasks in block)
- task vars (only for the task)
- extra vars (always win precedence)

The answer to your specific use case requires that you provide the location of the `var` files (as it cannot be inferred from the data provided) in the directory structure. Depending on where those files where placed, they have a different precedence.

I personally prefer to group data under `group_vars` (check the [best practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) document for the preferred layout), so I can assign data to groups of hosts, mainly because this most commonly maps directly to roles.